# shopify version - nothing shown

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to create a new theme in shopify and even after installing NPM, when I try to run the theme launch, it doesn't show an error but nothing happens either.

I followed this tutorial: https://shopify.dev/themes/getting-started/create

[image]

As you can see, absolutely nothing happens.

Thank you in advance for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my node from 14.5.3 version to 16.18.1 and all works now!